# Analysis of run time complexity

Tags: java, time-complexity

I need some help below I have some code I created for an assignment. I am having a hard time figuring out the time complexity of this algorithm. I looked at it and believe the O-notation is 0(n) and the function is `F(n)= 4 + 2n`.  But I think that is incorrect.

```
/**
*mostOften method 
*@param receives Array[] , int
*/

 static int mostOften(int array[] , int n){
 
 //Array to be sorted in ascending order
 Arrays.sort(array);
 
 //counts number of max occurrences in the array
 int maxO = 1;
 
 //Keeps track of the integer at Array[i].
 int result = array[0];
 
 //variable to count occurrences
 int count = 1;
 
 /**
 *loop passes through array in linear motion and compares index at i and index at
 * i - 1. For every possible outcome count and maxO are incremented accordingly.
 */
  for(int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++){ 
  
        //If integers are the same increment count.
            if (array[i] == array[i - 1]){ 
                count++;  
            }//close if statement
            
        // else if integers are not the same 
         else{
         
               //if count is larger thatn maxO that integer is the highers occurrence
                if (count > maxO){ 
            
                   //count is now maxO
                    maxO = count; 
               
               //replaces result with integers with highest occurrence.
                    result = array[i - 1]; 
                }//close if statement
             
            //reset count to 1.
                count = 1; 
            
            }//close else statement
         
  }//close for loop
  
      //@returns int data type
        return result;
  
 }//close mostOften method
```

Comment: *"But I think that is incorrect"* -  You need to explain why you think it is incorrect ... or else it is difficult to help you.

Comment: I'm unsure if the F(n) function I mentioned is correct or not for the time complexity. Perhaps I read my code wrong. I want to know if some else can let me know if I wrote the function correctly.

Comment: The `F(n)` function is impossible to give precisely because it depends on what is being counted.  But that's a side issue.  `F(n) = 4 + 2n` and `F(n) = 5 + 4n` give you the same `O` complexity.  The real issue is whether there are (should be) terms that are "larger" than `cn` for a constant `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to point out that Arrays.sort itself is O(n logn).
If we ignore that, the loop takes linear time.

Comment: lets say if I don't ignore it and take it into account then the code it self is n log n + n(for the loop) ?

Comment: Simplifies to O(n logn). Thank you very much! I been having a difficult time understanding time complexity, worst case and best case. Your help is very much appreciated.